# What is the difference between Expression.Variable() and Expression.Parameter()?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees

Both seem to return the same type, and have the same signature.

So what is the difference between them, and when should we use each?

Comment: `Expression.Variable` does not allows `ByRef` types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Expression.Variable` is used to declare a local variable within a block. `Expression.Parameter` is used to declare a parameter for an incoming value.

Now currently C# doesn't allow statement-bodied lambda expressions, but if it *did*, imagine:

```
// Not currently valid, admittedly...
Expression<Func<int, int>> foo = x =>
{
    int y = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    return x + y;
};
```

If this *were* valid, the C# compiler would generate code using `Expression.Parameter` for `x`, and `Expression.Variable` for `y`.

At least, that's my understanding. It's a real shame that the documentation for the two methods is basically the same :(

Comment: Thanks Jon! But since they return the same type, don't they only **semantically** different?

Comment: @shay__: I don't know what you mean by "only semantically different" given that semantics is meaning. I would expect the result of Expression.Variable to be invalid to pass into Expression.Lambda for example. It's a shame they're the same type, IMO.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean - you can call either Expression.Parameter or Expression.Variable, and it won't make any difference, actually. By "semantically" I mean that the **functionality** is the same, but they have different names for the reader, or maybe for future features... Is that correct?

Comment: @shay__: No, I'd expect them to behave differently, in the way I suggested. They may not, but you'd have to experiment to check. (Or view the source.)

Comment: Actually you can "emit" that code in C# 4.0 and above using the Expression.Block API.

Comment: Yeah, agree. Compiler can't generate such expression, however you can do it in runtime via Expression API. So it's not limit for .Net, but more likely it's a limit for existing C# compiler

Comment: @GeorgeLica: You can emit it in C# 2.0 targeting .NET 4.0... my point is that statement lambdas don't support expression trees *in C# itself*.

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, there is no difference, apart from the fact that `Variable()` does not allow `ref` types. To see that, you can look at [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ParameterExpression.cs,200):

```
public static ParameterExpression Parameter(Type type, string name) {
    ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull(type, "type");

    if (type == typeof(void)) {
        throw Error.ArgumentCannotBeOfTypeVoid();
    }

    bool byref = type.IsByRef;
    if (byref) {
        type = type.GetElementType();
    }

    return ParameterExpression.Make(type, name, byref);
}

public static ParameterExpression Variable(Type type, string name) {
    ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull(type, "type");
    if (type == typeof(void)) throw Error.ArgumentCannotBeOfTypeVoid();
    if (type.IsByRef) throw Error.TypeMustNotBeByRef();
    return ParameterExpression.Make(type, name, false);
}
```

As you can see, both methods call `ParameterExpression.Make()`, so the returned object will behave the same.